# Column binding in R

Tags: r, binding, dataframe

I am using the cbind command in R to bind many data.frames together and each data frame has the same column names so when I bind them all, R automatically changes the column names from their original names. For example, there is a column named "X" so for each binding it renames this X.1, X.2, X.3 etc. Is there a way for me to bind them without changing any of the column names and have multiple columns with the same name?

The reason I wish to do this is so I can sort the combined data.frame after by the column names to get all the equal named columns together in the same order they were in the combined data.frame.

Comment: Can you give a small example data set and a small example of what you want back.

Comment: (1) Wouldn't the sorting still work with the suffixed? (2) AFAIK the only way you'd be getting the suffixes at all is if you are needlessly calling `data.frame()` on the results of `cbind`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To illustrate the points from my comment:

```
> d1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5,b = 1:5)
> d2 <- data.frame(a = letters[1:5],b = letters[1:5])
> cbind(d1,d2)
  a b a b
1 1 1 a a
2 2 2 b b
3 3 3 c c
4 4 4 d d
5 5 5 e e

> data.frame(cbind(d1,d2))
  a b a.1 b.1
1 1 1   a   a
2 2 2   b   b
3 3 3   c   c
4 4 4   d   d
5 5 5   e   e

> x <- data.frame(cbind(d1,d2))
> sort(colnames(x))
[1] "a"   "a.1" "b"   "b.1"
> x[,order(colnames(x))]
  a a.1 b b.1
1 1   a 1   a
2 2   b 2   b
3 3   c 3   c
4 4   d 4   d
5 5   e 5   e
```

Comment: Yes you are right. That does actually work fine for what I need. Sorry I am fairly new to R. If I wanted to then remove a certain subset of columns is there an easy way to do this? Using your example, say we had many "a" columns and wanted to remove just those. Say a.1,a.2,a.3,a.4,etc.?

Comment: @user1836894 try somthing like `x[,-grep('.*[.].*',colnames(x))]` to remove dotted columns

Comment: @sebastian-c yes I think you're right. I wrote it as a comment so I haven't really test it.